# ValidationError: [u'Enter valid JSON']: Can load DJANGO JSON field in my local machine but not in remote production server

Tags: python, django, jsonfield

I have a field of type JSONField that basically contains this structure:

```
[{u'date': u'2021-11-24T13:51:47', u'text': u'todayone'},
 {u'date': u'2021-11-24T13:52:38', u'text': u'todaytwo'},
 {u'date': u'2021-11-24T13:53:26', u'text': u'todaythree'}]
```

When the field has more than 600 Entries, I can't load it in production but locally I can do it without problems. In production I receive the following error:

```
    /venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.pyc in __iter__(self)
     61         related_populators = get_related_populators(klass_info, select, db)
     62         for row in compiler.results_iter(results):
---> 63             obj = model_cls.from_db(db, init_list, row[model_fields_start:model_fields_end])
     64             if related_populators:
     65                 for rel_populator in related_populators:

/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.pyc in from_db(cls, db, field_names, values)
    581             values.reverse()
    582             values = [values.pop() if f.attname in field_names else DEFERRED for f in cls._meta.concrete_fields]
--> 583         new = cls(*values)
    584         new._state.adding = False
    585         new._state.db = db

/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.pyc in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    500                 if val is _DEFERRED:
    501                     continue
--> 502                 _setattr(self, field.attname, val)
    503         else:
    504             # Slower, kwargs-ready version.

/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jsonfield/subclassing.pyc in __set__(self, obj, value)
     39         # we can definitively tell if a value has already been deserialized
     40         # More: https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield/issues/33
---> 41         obj.__dict__[self.field.name] = self.field.pre_init(value, obj)
     42 
     43 

/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jsonfield/fields.pyc in pre_init(self, value, obj)
     78                         return json.loads(value, **self.load_kwargs)
     79                     except ValueError:
---> 80                         raise ValidationError(_("Enter valid JSON"))
     81 
     82         return value

ValidationError: [u'Enter valid JSON']
```

Both environments have the next settings:

```
Python version: 2.7.11
Django version: 1.11.29

Json packages:
jsonfield==1.0.1
jsonschema==3.2.0
simplejson==3.6.5
```

I don't see any memory issues in the server.

Comment: i dont know why it works local because your json is not a valid json check your text field doesn't have single quote

Comment: @Carlos My bad, I wrote it with errors here. I edited it now, thanks.